# What is the best way to do a pd.concat horizontally in pandas, matching on a column?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Example:

```
Df1: ID, Variable_1, Variable_2
Df2: ID, Variable_1a, Variable_2a
```

I want the resulting Df to be matched on ID values (which are identical), and have the following format:

```
Df3: ID, Variable_1, Variable_2, Variable_1a, Variable_2a
```

I tried: `Df3 = pd.concat([Df1, Df2], axis=1, join='outer')`, but it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: Include sample dataframes so people can reproduce your example. Also format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Df1.merge(Df2, on="ID", how="outer")`? Here's a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "varA", "varB"], [2, "varX", "varY"], [3, "varC", "varD"]], columns=["ID", "Variable_1", "Variable_2"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "varA_a", "varB_a"], [2, "varX_a", "varY_a"]], columns=["ID", "Variable_1a", "Variable_2a"])

print(df1)
print()
print(df2)
print()
merged = df1.merge(df2, on="ID", how='outer')
print(merged)
```

it outputs:

```
   ID Variable_1 Variable_2
0   1       varA       varB
1   2       varX       varY
2   3       varC       varD

   ID Variable_1a Variable_2a
0   1      varA_a      varB_a
1   2      varX_a      varY_a

   ID Variable_1 Variable_2 Variable_1a Variable_2a
0   1       varA       varB      varA_a      varB_a
1   2       varX       varY      varX_a      varY_a
2   3       varC       varD         NaN         NaN
```

which is what I think you're looking for.